# How to apply plugin for Stylus in Vue 2 project with webpack template

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, stylus

I have a Vue2 project with [Webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) and I am using [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) as CSS preprocessor (stylus, stylus-loader already installed and working).

I can not find a way to apply plugins for Stylus like [rupture](http://jescalan.github.io/rupture/).

I tried to modify the options in `build/utils.js` for the stylus loader like so:

```
stylus: generateLoaders('stylus', {use: [require('rupture')()]}),
styl: generateLoaders('stylus', {use: [require('rupture')()]})
```

Also tried to `import` rupture from `<style></style>` tag in `App.vue` like:

```
@import 'rupture/rupture/index.styl' // also 'rupture/index.styl'
```

Also tried importing it from `main.js` but nothing worked so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@import '~rupture/rupture/index.styl' `?

Comment: Super, didn't know about the `~`, this did work!

Comment: Modifying the options should have done the job, though. It's weird that it doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, could it be because of Node 8.0? There is no adequate error message.. Just stylus-loader fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `@import` solution is local and works only for the current component. So it's not applicable for requiring mixins that are supposed to be global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have come up with a solution which utilizes the `import` option of Stylus like so:

```
stylus: generateLoaders('stylus', {

  // unfortunately `use` option throws error
  // use: [require('nib')(), require('rupture')()]

  // import to the rescue
  import: [
    '~nib/index.styl',
    '~rupture/rupture/index.styl',
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/cfg.styl')
  ]
}),
```

***Note**: If any path provided in the `import` option is incorrect the server silently falls into kind of hanging state and doesn't start - no errors are thrown.*